# youtube-data-api with vue js and axios

Tags: vue.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am a beginner developer and just learned basic javascript 4 months ago, and vue over the last 4 days. I have never worked with google api before. What I am trying to do by using the vue documentation is display a youtube playlist based on music genre. I keep getting:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'data:text;charset=utf-8,' (redirected
>   from 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id') from origin
>   'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

followed by:

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking
>   'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to
>   make the page more responsive.

Google support told me to post on stackoverflow to get a google engineer to help. Here is the get request i'm using and I removed the playlistID and apikey from the url

```
created(){
    this.getPlaylist();
  },
  methods: {
    getPlaylist: function ()  {
    axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&id=PLfY-m4YMsF-OM1zG80pMguej_Ufm8t0VC&key=AIzaSyCnGeoYhG3HXL6j8bIH-mwgwCHYyqdBW4s', function(response){
    this.playlist = response.items
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch( function(error){
    console.log('Error: ', error)
  })}}
```

Comment: Have you included your API domains to add proper headers to its response?

Comment: @jess I am not exactly sure what you mean. as I said in my post I am very new to vue and javascript as a whole. I have been following guides on using get requests with api on youtube, as well as examples from programs in github.